# ISNULL vs IS NULL in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm analyzing differences between `ISNULL(field,0) = 0` and `(field IS NULL OR field = 0)` in performance terms. This where is for Table A joined with a LEFT join with Table B.

```
select * 
from tabA
left join tabB on tabB.id = tabA.foreignID
where ISNULL(tabB.field,0) = 0

select *
from tabA
left join tabB on tabB.id = tabA.foreignID
where ISNULL(tabB.field,0) = 1

select *
from tabA
left join tabB on tabB.id = tabA.foreignID
where ISNULL(tabB.id,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(tabB.field,0) = 1
```

I have an index on `"field"`, and I know that `ISNULL` isn't a sargable function so can invalidate the use of the index. But I can't demonstrate it.

Thanks

Comment: Turn on "Display Actual Execution Plan" and run your queries. Hover your mouse over the arrows and check for number of rows read in each table. More rows = slower. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you're asking "which one is faster?" well, did you test it? Did you compare execution plans? Do you see any _tangible_ differences? I doubt you'll find either of those to be sargable, but see [Performance Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Personally, I find the magic values of 0 or 1 to be extra theater for no gain.

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is. But in cases like this, a `UNION ALL` usually performs best: `SELECT X FROM Y WHERE z IS NULL UNION ALL SELECT X FROM Y WHERE z = 0`

Comment: I had semplified my situation to understand the behavior. I know that bibliografy explain that field IS (NOT) NULL in AND/OR with the condition is better than use ISNULL(field,0)=filter, I try to envaluate this rule in a simple test but I didn't

Comment: You likely can't demonstrate the performance differences for two reasons; your test data is insufficient in quantity and random distribution (small data sets can be read in to memory), and your indexes are overly simplistic (having separate indexes for individual columns is vastly different from having compound indexes where each index covers multiple columns). These two reasons also overlap because sometimes the where clause may be most important (index on field, foreignId) though usually the join is most important (index on foreignId, field).

Answer (score 1):

First, with a join like this, using `SELECT *` will limit the optimizer's ability to select a good index from either table. It is possible that it will force a scan (all rows are read) where a seek (only a select subset are read) would be better.

Yes, `ISNULL` and `IS NULL` will force make you predicates non-sargable. You *can* create a filtered index for NULLs *in a table* but not for Left Joins.

Running the query with "Include ***actual*** execution plan" turned on you can determine the best way to go. First some sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE #tabA (foreignID INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE #tabB (ID        INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Field INT);

INSERT #tabA VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
INSERT #tabB(Field) VALUES(0),(0),(1),(1),(3),(4),(6);
```

Without proper indexes in place, the performance considerations are not a big deal, you will scan all rows in both tables then apply some filters that further slow you down. Below are 6 queries using SARGable and non-SARGable predicates. They won't produce the same result set but will better understand the performance implications for each query.

```
;-- <1>
select *
from      #tabA AS tabA
left join #tabB AS tabB 
  on      tabB.id=tabA.foreignID
where     ISNULL(tabB.field,0)=0 -- [Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(isnull(#tabB.[Field] as [tabB].[Field],(0)))

;-- <2>
select *
from      #tabA AS tabA
left join #tabB AS tabB 
  on      tabB.id=tabA.foreignID
where     tabB.field = 0
 OR       tabB.field IS NULL -- does a cross join for 49 rows (7 in A * 7 in B)
;-- <3>

select *
from      #tabA AS tabA
left join #tabB AS tabB 
  on      tabB.id=tabA.foreignID
where     tabB.field = 0 -- Does a seek for only 2 rows
```

**Query1 vs Query2**

[image]

Here we are guaranteed the same results but notice how, in the plan, the ISNULL(x,0)=0 gets an extra filter in the form of a Compute Scalar operation. This will make the first query slower as you add more rows.

**Query2 vs Query3**
[image]

When I drop the ISNULL predicate (Query 3) I get an index seek vs a scan. Query2 is examining 49 rows (7 in A, 7 in b); removing he 'IS NULL' filter allows a seek on Table A. 7 Rows are still scanned from Table A but only 2 (not 7) from Table B. The rows are not cross joined, so only 9 rows are read. Thats a ~5X reduction in rows read. Imagine if both tables had a million rows, Query 2 would scan and cross join all the records for a total of 1,000,000,0000,0000 (1M * 1M) rows.

**Query 3 vs Query 4**
[image]

Here each query has a single predicate. For Query3 the predicate is `tabB.field = 0` for Query4 the predicate is `tabB.field IS NULL`. This is another example of how both `ISNULL()` (a built-in function) and `IS NULL` (built-in ANSI SQL predicate logic) both circumvent your ability to leverage indexes.